# How would I decompose an NSString into individual characters?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

So I have a method that takes an NSString as an argument, and I would like that method to basically decompose that sting into individual characters and store them in an array(NSArray).

I other words I would like to read each character in the string and store the individual characters in an array and in the same order, so that I can process the individual characters at a later time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate through the string, use characterAt - and append each character to an NSMutableArray.

But if your doing that - why bother putting them in the NSArray at all?

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray] alloc] initWithCapacity:[string length]];

for (i=0;i<[string length];i++) {
  unichaar ch;
  ch = [string  characterAtIndex:i];
  NSLog(@"Processing charachter %c",ch);

   // If you really want
  [myArray addObject:(id) ch];
}
```

Comment: Yeah good point, I might as well process as I go. Thanks a lot i'll give that a try.

Comment: corrections: 1) it's `unichar` 2) `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:` will use the default allocator. the default allocator assumes `id`, and will send retain/release messages to the unichars - -which will of course crash. you have two options: use NSString for each character, or drop down to allocate a CFMutableArray using a custom allocator which does not perform reference counting on the unichars

Comment: @Justin - thanks, yes, your right. The NSArray was an afterthought - because, like I suggested, he shouldn't even bother needing it.

Comment: @Brad yes - i also agree that using/allocating an NSString for each character would kill performance, compared to using a unichar. sometimes that is insignificant. there are also rare cases where an array of single char NSStrings is useful.

Comment: Could also use `-getCharacters:range:` to copy all the chars into a c-style array of unichars, which could be more efficient than extracting characters individually with `-characterAtIndex:`. Still, best solution is probably to process as you go and not use an array at all.

Comment: You shouldn't process a unichar with %c, they can easily be higher than 127.

Comment: so iterating works great but I do have a problem, the "processing" I do requires delayed method calls. By delaying method calls inside a loop I noticed that the loop is still runs, instead of waiting for the methods to complete. How can I get the loop to wait for the delayed methods to finish before continuing on to the next iteration?

Comment: Do these delayed method calls have any facility to tell someone they're done? Like through a selector or delegate function?

Comment: well i'm delaying them using [self performSelector:@(methodCall) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];

Comment: Everybody reading this should really read JanX2's answer: enumerateSubstringsInRange: is the only way to do this and get consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not normally this judgmental, but the current answers will work… until they don’t!

There is only a single way in ObjC/Foundation to enumerate actual Unicode characters:

```
- (void)enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange)range options:(NSStringEnumerationOptions)opts usingBlock:(void (^)(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop))block
```

using the option

```
NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
```

The problem here is best illustrated using Emoji:

(Unicode name: PILE OF PO, Code point: U+1F4A9) is 0xD83DDCA9 when represented as the UTF-16 Cocoa/Foundation/CoreFoundation uses internally. You will get two (broken, invalid) entries with the other methods.

If your strings are long and performance becomes an issue, but memory is not, you could use UTF-32 and you can once again access your characters in constant time. Just store them in a C array or a C++ vector. Or just wrap the 32-bit values in NSNumber and use an NSArray if performance is not all that critical…

I strongly recommend reading through [NSString and Unicode](http://www.objc.io/issue-9/unicode.html) from objc.io issue #9.

Edit 2016-05-15: The term “character” in this context is not well defined and can be misleading. What I refer to above as a “character” is actually a Unicode code point. Swift does the right thing here and defines a character as “what a user thinks of as a character.”

Answer (score 0):

Besides Brad answer (where he shows you can certainly store each character in a `NSArray` instance if you want), you also have the more straightforward opportunity to get the `NSString` value as a plain old **C null terminated string**. So you can iterate it like this:

```
char c;
int i = 0;
const char *buffer = [nsstringInstance cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
while (c = buffer[i++]) {
    // iterating using c char

}
```

Comment: But what if the NSString contains non-ascii characters, or is longer than 1024 characters? Note also that `-getCString:` is deprecated as of iOS2.0.

Comment: @David: true. Changed it for cStringUsingEncoding.